# Is Test oriented development bad practice against the Test driven development

Tags: tdd, software-design

In this not so new article http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part3.html I saw something that get my attention - TDD and TOD - as TOD is Test oriented development where developer is alternate between writing the code and tests.

To me this is not a bad practice and for developers that don't have experience with TDD is like step forward before they go strictly with TDD.

The problem here is more on conceptual and development flow level. Tests are to help you and get your idea on the things that you will be implemented and that's why mixing is wrong to me.

However I can't see if someone is doing that - how wrong is it? I do a quick research for TOD and didn't find anything useful. Is there some way of doing stuff with TOD or this is term used only in the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test Oriented development is not a widely accepted term AFAIK

What are the pros of writing the test "around" the same time as code is written as opposed to "before"? If it isn't "before", isn't it "after"?

Some cons off the top of my head are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199313)

Comment: I saw what you've wrote in your theme - this is helpful to me- thanks. We are about to integrate TDD in our software development - until now we go with integration tests of already implemented components and I was thinking to encouraging people how to do that and how not to do it.